# How do I find the engagements seen on the instagram UI through the graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I need to provide the engagement rate to a client. This needs to include organic and paid reach & engagements.

[image: the post on the instagram UI]

[image: the boosted post campaign]

[image: duplicate boosted posts; for whatever reason this always happens]

[image: post id engagements; likes + comments = engagements; according to support this is the organic engagements]

[image: insight "engagements" from the insights graph api]

[image: the instagram ads api; showing the id of the boosted post campaigns and the two duplicate posts]

[image: the engagements for the greater of the duplicate posts]

[image: the engagements for the lesser of the duplicate posts]

I have attached seperate screenshots to show that the values in the graph API/business manager/instagram UI do not match up.

How can I find the engagements seen in the instagram UI, and the reach associated with these engagements, to provide my clients with the true engagement rate? There are two different "engagements" provided by the instagram API, and the ads API provides engagements but no combination of these paid/organic engagements add up to be what is seen on the instagram UI

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access that trough a page that is connected to instagram business.

```
[instagram / facebook authentication policy][1]
```

You can request that on graph api explorer with the following query:

```
me?fields=instagram_business_account
```

Afterwards you can make all kinds of request for instance:

```
insights?metric=reach&period=days_28
```